# Adding a custom button to mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

Im using @angular/material - 10.2.7 version.

```
<mat-datepicker-actions>
    <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
</mat-datepicker-actions>
```

This construct doesn't work (doesn't support my version?) How can I solve this problem?

**error:**

```
    'mat-datepicker-actions' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-datepicker-actions' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-datepicker-actions' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: `import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`

Comment: Did't work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `MatDatepickerModule` into the module your component is declared in.

E.g. if your component is `FormComponent` and belongs to the `AppModule` module, then within `app.module.ts`, you have to:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., MatDatepickerModule],
  declarations: [..., FormComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Of course, you need to first npm install the material library if you have yet to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the datepicker actions inside the `mat-date-range-picker` tag.

So it should look this:

```
<mat-date-range-picker #yourRefHere>
    <mat-datepicker-actions>
        <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
    </mat-datepicker-actions>
</mat-date-range-picker>
```